# Show flash video inline on Google+ and LinkedIn

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, linkedin-api, google-plus, schema.org

Can you show flash video directly on Google+ or LinkedIn newsfeed?
Eg. when you post a link that contains proper OpenGraph data on Facebook, Facebook shows video embedded in post on your Wall. Google+ and LinkedIn do the same when using YouTube videos. My question is how to do that on Google+ or LinkedIn with any flash video?

I tried Schema.org but it doesn't work:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36666425/social_test/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google+ currently has a whitelist of only a few media sites that they allow embeds from. Look for announcements on their blog if they add to the list: http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/

I don't know about LinkedIn.